# What do you call a person that wants to kill people but doesn't actually kill them?

Tags: epithet-requests

A killer is a person that has already killed someone. The term i'm looking for is someone who wants to kill people but never does. Only has a tendency to do so, or wants to kill them but never really does.

Comment: did 'he' kill or torture any other living thing is his childhood?

Comment: No. but now he has wants to do so, has a feeling to do so but won't do it.

Comment: Are you basically saying that you know someone who might know someone who wants to kill?

Comment: "What do you call a person that wants to kill people but doesn't actually kill them?" ............................Angry?

Comment: @Zebrafish Not quite. Lets assume Hypothetical person "XYZ". XYZ is someone who wants to kill people because he doesn't like them. He wants to kill people because he is angry at them. But he never really gets to killing them. Just has this murderous intent. What do you call such a person?

Comment: @pyobum Angry - "feeling or showing strong annoyance, displeasure, or hostility; full of anger." Angry doesn't quite define murderous intent... Anger causes murderour intent but you can't call a person who wants to kill people 'angry' .

Comment: @Battu007, it depends, if there's a group of people he feels hostility towards because they did something to him, I'd say he's angry and potentially violent. However if you're talking about someone who has desires of killing everyone but doesn't, then I think it's more in line with psychopathy or antisocial personality disorder

Comment: I was joking with "angry." Being serious--I think you may have just answered your own question with "murderous." The definition includes the *intent* (or desire) to kill someone.

Comment: I see the tag 'epithet-request'. Are you looking for a word or term to yell at someone? Or are you looking for a descriptive term to tell others?

Comment: wannabe-psychopath?

Comment: I think we call them civilized ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Homicidal ideation** is a term describing the mental disorder such a person suffers from. I don't know of a noun describing the person. *homicidal ideator* doesn't seem to be a thing. According to Wikipedia:

> "Homicidal ideation is a common medical term for thoughts about homicide."[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidal_ideation)

According to lecture notes (for preparing to be an emergency nurse) on Study.com:

> "Homicidal ideation is a thought pattern that may lead to actual homicide or the killing of one person by another. In this lesson, we will discuss the assessment of a person's risk for committing homicide, and related causes and management."[2](https://study.com/academy/lesson/homicidal-ideation-definition-assessment-management.html)

**Attribution**

[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidal_ideation) Homicidal ideation. (2018, March 12). Retrieved March 22, 2018, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidal_ideation

[2](https://study.com/academy/lesson/homicidal-ideation-definition-assessment-management.html) Jankowski, P. (n.d.). Homicidal Ideation: Definition, Assessment & Management. Retrieved March 22, 2018, from https://study.com/academy/lesson/homicidal-ideation-definition-assessment-management.html

Comment: This was my first thought too. Note that this is particularly technical in the medical field and not likely to be used in conversation outside of medicine.

Comment: @Mitch thanks for your reply, as an outsider to medicine I quite like the word, in particular the _ideation_ part (when I first read it I thought it was _idealisation_, as in they idealise the idea of murder). To me it sounds like a term you might hear in a series like _Criminal Minds_, some Googling reveals [they actually have used the term on the series](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=13169).